# Call to undefined method stdClass::count() in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have an issue with a count function in drupal 7.

Code is :

```
    $sql = "select count(Status) from TB_Aanmeldingen where (Status= 'Ja' or Status='Ja, met kleine') and ID_Wedstrijd = :match";
    $args = array(':match' => $match);
    $row = db_query($sql, $args)->fetchObject();
    $aantal = $row->count(Status);
```

Error message:

```
    Call to undefined method stdClass::count()
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with:

```
 $aantal = $row->count(Status);
```

Do a print_r or var_dump of the $row object, and you'll see what the structure is. db_query returns a DatabaseStatementInterface, and you're getting an object from it. But the object doesn't have a function you're trying to call.

Instead, debug, print out, and debug the value of $row, and get the value you're looking for.

Also, look into db_select. It's better to use that then db_query.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7